# plotting a confidence interval for regression line by Theil-Sen estimator in a pandas timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, time-series, stat

I am working on a timeseries DataFrame like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[ '1990','1991','1992','1993','1994','1995','1996','1997','1998','1999','2000'],
                           'count':[96,184,148,154,160,149,124,274,322,301,300]})
```

I am interested to find regression line using `Theil-Sen's slope estimator` and the function from `Scipy`

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.theilslopes.html

as in following `code` snippet:

```
from scipy import stats                                         


x = df['year'].astype(float)
y = df['count']


res = stats.theilslopes(y, x, 0.90)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x, y, 'b.')

ax.plot(x, res[1] + res[0] * x, 'r-')


plt.ylabel('count')
plt.xlabel('year')

plt.show()
```

I could find the `Theil-Sen's regression line` but while adding codes for visualizing `confidence interval`, the visualization is some non-realistic.

```
    ax.plot(x, res[1] + res[2] * x, 'r--')
    ax.plot(x, res[1] + res[3] * x, 'r--')
```

Is there some way, I can get a visualization with `theil-sen's slope estimator` and `confidence interval` as in this figure:[image]

your kind help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.theilslopes.html#scipy-stats-mstats-theilslopes) You would have to obtain your own confidence interval estimate as none is given, and you cannot base it just on the slope uncertainty alone. Error propagation or Monte Carlo are some ways you could go about estimating the confidence interval.

However, the reason your plot looks off is due to normalization, if you normalize the x-axis before you fit, you get a normal looking confidence interval instead of one that blows up. Yet, it's not a real confidence interval as the only uncertainty is the slope so it crosses to zero at the intercept. Here I have chosen to normalize to -1,1 as is appropriate to produce the figure you want. But I have provided some helper functions as well to help you do this differently in the future.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[ '1990','1991','1992','1993','1994','1995','1996','1997','1998','1999','2000'],
                           'count':[96,184,148,154,160,149,124,274,322,301,300]})

from scipy import stats                                         
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = df['year'].astype(float)
y = df['count']

def norm0_1(x):
    return (x - x.min())/ (x.max()-x.min())

def denorm(x_norm, x):
    return (x_norm * (x.max() - x.min()) + x.min())

x_norm = 2*norm0_1(x)-1

res = stats.theilslopes(y, x_norm, 0.90)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x, y, 'b.')
ax.plot(x, res[1] + res[0] * x_norm, 'r-')
ax.plot(x, res[1] + res[2] * x_norm, 'r--')
ax.plot(x, res[1] + res[3] * x_norm, 'r--')


plt.ylabel('count')
plt.xlabel('year')

plt.show()
```

Normed version:

[image: normed]

The default version produced by your code:

[image]

Comment: @Peshal1067 Please mark this answer as accepted if this solved your problem.